# Set NTFS file permission for Wild Card [like *.doc]

Tags: permissions, ntfs, wildcards

How to set NTFS file permission for Wild Card [like *.doc]? Is it possible?

Comment: SamSol: this is a rather excessive number of questions you're posting all at once.  please stop posting new questions, and spread them out over a few days.  give people a chance to answer some before asking more.

Comment: SamSol: please stop posting so many questions all at once.  take a rest for today; you can come back tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cacls` command from a command window to change file permissions.

For example, `cacls *.doc /P Everyone:F` will grant everyone full access to all the *.doc files in the current directory.

`cacls filename.ext` prints out the current permissions and `cacls` on it's own gives usage instructions.